# Fetching multiple rows based on two comparisons in each row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table as follows

```
col1 col2        col3
a    01/01/2001   1.1
a    01/02/2001   1.2
a    01/03/2001   1.3
b    02/03/2004   2.1
b    02/04/2004   2.2
b    02/05/2004   2.3
```

I want to be able to fetch rows based on multiple comparisons on each row. That is, fetch rows where I have `(a,01/01/2001)` and `(b,02/05/2004)`. Something that would look like,

```
Select * from table where col1,col2 in (('a','01/01/2001'),('b','02/05/2004'))
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE 
     (col1 = 'a' AND col2 = '01/01/2001')
     OR
     (col1 = 'b' AND col2 = '02/05/2004')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your original code was so close but not quite there. You just needed to put the fields on the left hand side of the condition in brackets

```
Select * from table where (col1,col2) in (('a','01/01/2001'),('b','02/05/2004'))
```